# Css - Div causing white space at the top of a page

Tags: css, html

I have narrowed down the culprit to either a SPAN or a DIV in lines 27-33 but cant quite get it... if i remove the span that makes the font below the press muted, it fixes the spacing issue at the top of the page but makes that text way to large

u.neighborrow.com/items/indexb

```
<div id="slide_one" class="bg"><!--slide #1-->

<div class="slide-content">

   <div class="nhome">
       <div style="margin-top:22px;color:#000;font-size:30px;margin-left:200px;width:408px">
The cheaper, greener, easier, better way to have stuff.
            <span style="font-size: 13px; position: relative; top: -2px"> <br /></span>

            <?php echo $form->create('Item', array('controller' => 'items', 'action' => 'recent/2')); ?>


            <div class="input text required">
                <label for="ItemItem"></label><input type="text" id="ItemItem" value="" maxlength="255" style="font-size: 25px; width: 200px; margin: 5px 0pt;" name="data[Item][item]">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" style="font-size: 22px" />
            </div>


            <?php echo $form->end(); ?>
           <div style="font-size: 13px; position: relative; top: -2px; line-height: 1.4em;"> <strong>Search Tips:</strong> Need a camera or a book for a trip? Want to try an iPAD before you buy it? Need a tool for a project or a tent for an event?  <br />
       Borrow these things from your neighbors, The <i>owner</i>-ship has SAILED!</div>

    <span style="font-weight:normal;color:#ccc;font-size:14px;line-height:20px">Still not sure what to borrow? <br />
    Browse the borrowables or  <br />
    Lend something safely and securely<br />
            </span>

<div>
 <div style="padding:5px;text-align:center"><img src="/images/press_wide.jpg"></div>
    <span style="font-weight:normal;color:#ccc;font-size:14px;line-height:20px">  The media <a href="http://facebook.com/neighborrow">adores us</a>,  our users <a href="/pages/about">love us,</a>our friends <i>like us</i>,
            <center><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=www.neighborrow.com&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=350&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height: 30px; text-align: center;margin-top:0px;"></iframe></center>
            (oh yeah, and mother earth has a crush on us:)</div></span>         


    <hr color="#CCC" />



</div>
</div>
                    </div>     
                    </div>


</div>
```

and i know i need to get rid of the inline styles:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got some crazy margins:

```
<div class="main-content" style="margin-top:200px">
```

Comment: that looks like the culprit- cant find where its rendering from.. is it the master layout file or inline somewhere (thanks!)

Comment: found it, thank you -- why on EARTH would someone have put that in?:) good thing im doing this myself from now on:)

Answer (score 1):

It's in div class="main content" style="margin-top: 200px">  It seems to be inline on line 325

Comment: I suggest using Firefox's firebug to find these issues.